# ViewPager for multiple Activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to implement a ViewPager that have multiple activities. I'm following this [example](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) but this doesnt look that uses multiple activities, but Fragments. If anyone can explain me how to implement this. What I want is to scroll between different screens, and each screen does its own job.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to use multiple activities instead of multiple fragments?

Comment: Because I dont know how fragments works. How can I build it. I'm reading this from docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm trying to implement a ViewPager that have multiple activities.

I doubt this is possible, and to the extent that it is, it would use deprecated techniques like `ActivityGroup`.

> What I want is to scroll between different screens, and each screen does its own job.

Use fragments, as @Glendon Trullinger suggested.

> How can I build it.

Use the example that you linked to. Or look at the `Support13Demos` in your SDK's `extras/` folder tree, which demonstrate `ViewPager`. When you have *specific*, *concrete* questions regarding the use of fragments, ask another question here on StackOverflow.